# How to determine multicolor accent color on watchOS with SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, watchos, widgetkit, accent-color

Here you can see how `.accessoryRectangular` look like for Color.accentColor `multicolor` and `red`.

[image]
[image]

There is a way how to fix it properly. But first I need to determine if user selected multicolor or not.

Since `.accentColor` is defined the following not optional way:

```
public static var accentColor: Color { get }
```

is there any way to check if it is multicolor or not? I thought that multicolor is when accentColor is nil... but I was wrong. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how are you able to get the current complication "accentColor" (I've ended up in your question because of that).

But for your original question,
There's `WidgetRenderingMode` environment variable (since iOS 16 / watchOS 9).

So you can switch based on it. Here is the snippet from the link below:

```
@Environment(\.widgetRenderingMode) var renderingMode

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
       switch renderingMode {
        case .fullColor:
           Text("Full color")
        case .accented:
           ZStack {
               Circle(...)
               VStack {
                   Text("Accented")
                       .widgetAccentable()
                   Text("Normal")
               }
           }
        case .vibrant:
           Text("Full color")
        default:
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/widgetrenderingmode